# Building model to select values at point from folder of several raster layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iteration, inverse-distance-weighted

I am using ModelBuilder to interpolate values with inverse distance weighting, iterated through several rows, resulting in many raster datasets - one raster layer per row. I have this and all the raster files are in one folder.

Next, I would like to select the value at specific coordinates, and repeat for each of the raster files, resulting in a table with a row for each coordinate-rasterlayer (so, total number of rows in the final table = # coordinates*number of raster layers in folder).

I added on to the original model, but it is creating an overall estimate from all the raster datapoints (so, total number of rows in this incorrect table = # coordinates)

How can I fix this model?

Here is the model I have now. 
[image]

This works through the IDW step, creating this output, which is a raster layer per row in the original data

[image]

The goal is to create at table with estimates for each centroid coordinate from each raster layer. The zip_centroid is a point dataset with lon and lat I need estimates for.

Comment: Did you try adding inline_variable in your output, such as o3_2005_%Value% and then Merge the outputs?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: adding the inline variable worked! Now trying to figure out how to merge all the tables into one wide table by coordinates. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your model is overwriting the final output after each iteration. To avoid that you can use your `Value` [inline_variable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm). Changing your output to `o3_2005_%Value%` will create separate copies of your Sample tables. The last step, merging all output tables, can be done by using `Merge` tool after a successful run of your model.

However, if you want to keep all processes in ModelBuilder, you should employ [sub-model approach](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm). I think you should add `Collect Values` tool to your current model to collect all Sample outputs and make this the **Output Parameter**. In a new model, you should add this model and Merge tool, and make your previous model's output (Collect Values) as the input to Merge.